# 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to get Kafka to work  for the first time.  I get the error as described below. Any reason why Kafka would throw this error?

The error:

> [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer
>   clientId=producer-1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a
>   matching listener, including [test1-0]

```
port =9020
advertised.host.name=10.44.72.204
advertised.port=9020
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kafka partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571823/kafka-partitions-have-leader-brokers-without-a-matching-listener)

Comment: Hi @ARAVINTHAN, did you find what was your issue? If yes, care to share? :)